# Sizes of kernels of homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a problem that I have been stuck on for two hours. I would like to check if I have      made any progress or I am just going in circles.

**Problem: Let $\alpha:G \rightarrow H, \beta:H \rightarrow K$ be group homomorphisms. Which is larger, $\ker(\beta\alpha)$ or $\ker(\alpha)$?**

**My work:** $\ker(\alpha)<G, \ker(\beta\alpha)<G, |G|=|\ker\alpha|*|im\alpha|=|\ker\beta|*|im\beta|$

$|G|=|\ker\alpha|[G:\ker\alpha]=|\ker\beta|[G:\ker\beta]$

$|im\alpha|$ divides $|G|$ and $|H|$

$|im\beta\alpha|$ divides $|G|$ and $|K|$

$|ker(\beta\alpha)|=\frac{|G|}{|im(\beta\alpha)|}, |ker(\alpha)|=\frac{|G|}{|im(\alpha)|}$

$\frac{|\ker(\beta\alpha)|}{|\ker\alpha|} \leq \frac{|H|}{|im(\beta\alpha)|}$

With similar analysis, I get $|\ker(\beta\alpha)| \geq \frac{|G|}{|K|}$ and $|\ker(\alpha)| \geq \frac{|G|}{|H|}$.

This seems like too much work with zero output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g \in \ker{\alpha}$, then $$\beta\alpha(g) = \beta(e_H) = e_K$$ and so $g \in \ker \beta\alpha$. This proves that $$\ker\alpha \subseteq \ker\beta\alpha$$and shows that $\ker\beta\alpha$ is at least as large as $\ker\alpha$.

Comment: Great answer. Is this the best we can do though? Can I figure out the exact sizes based on my work above?